# Understanding sysmon output

Tags: linux, memory

When I run the sysmon script, I get the following output:

```
22948     root           4673956K       d3
22945     root           4673692K       d3
23037     pick           4599952K       d3
23032     pick           4599952K       d3
23028     pick           4599952K       d3
23023     pick           4599952K       d3
23018     pick           4599952K       d3
23013     pick           4599952K       d3
23008     pick           4599952K       d3
23003     pick           4599952K       d3
22998     pick           4599952K       d3
22992     pick           4599952K       d3
22987     pick           4599952K       d3
22982     pick           4599952K       d3
22978     pick           4599952K       d3
22974     pick           4599952K       d3
22970     pick           4599952K       d3
22966     pick           4599952K       d3
22961     pick           4599952K       d3
22956     pick           4599952K       d3
```

The total memory for the processes listed add to more than the physical memory in the system. Can you explain to me what's going on here? And is there a way to get the actual memory used by all processes?

The sysmon script is located here: https://github.com/shovon8/sysmon/blob/master/sysmon.

Comment: You're counting shared libraries more than once, probably once per process. A lot of what you see as process memory is shared libraries.

Comment: Is there a way of getting memory used without shared libraries?